# Show for a constructor

Tags: haskell

Why does it complain about this code:

```
data Point = Point {
              x, y :: Int
            } deriving (Show)

main = print $ Point (15 20)
```

by saying:

```
No instance for (Show (Int -> Point))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (Int -> Point))
```

Comment: "(15 20)" is not valid syntax so my bet is you are getting a syntax error first and then a type error on on the expression "print $ Point" becuase to recover the parser left out "(15 20)". I could be missing some information however

Comment: @Jake it is valid syntax, but `15` is not a function so it cannot be applied to `20`.

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't think about it actually being valid syntax. Regardless you should neber see that in valid Haskell

Comment: @Jake But it can compile!  You might need `Text.Show.Functions` and flexible instances but... `main = print $ Point (15 20)`

`instance (Integral a, Num a) => Num (a -> Int) where
    fromInteger n = fromIntegral ∘ (+ (fromIntegral n))`   Now you've seen it, for better or worse!

Comment: Wow I never thought would be possible. Kudos. But that was defiantly for worse lol.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your bracketing is wrong.  Bracketing the `(15 20)` makes the compiler treat it as one argument to `Point`, and you're missing the second.  If you remove those brackets to leave `Point 15 20` it will work.

Answer (score 9):

**What is Wrong**

```
data Point = Point {
              x, y :: Int
            } deriving (Show)
```

It might become more obvious if we express the constructor `Point` as a function:

```
Point :: Int -> Int -> Point
```

If you know the syntax of function application then this becomes really clear:

```
main = print $ Point 15 20
```

**Why This Error**

As for why the broken code gets your particular error, consider how this is type-checked.  We have the expression:

```
Point ( ...something... )
```

And if `Point :: Int -> Int -> Point` then `Point something` must be of type `Int -> Point` (`Point` applied to any single argument has said type).  Now you see how it concludes you are trying to call `print` on something typed `Int -> Point` and thus complains about the missing instance - it doesn't even consider the bad expression of `(15 20)`.